# How to get Laravel 5 to work with Stapler?

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5

I keep getting a `Class Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\LaravelStaplerServiceProvider.php: not found`

I have tried using `Providers\L5ServiceProvider.php` instead as a provider in the `config\app.php` but that also gives the same error when I fire `composer update`

Any work around?

EDIT: please note that the directory `Providers` is not being fetched with the rest of the package, for some reason.

Comment: You may need to use dev-master in your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

`$php composer.phar require codesleeve/laravel-stapler`

Then add `'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'` to providers array in config/app.php.